# How to convert date to string and compare using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Part of Sql Query:

```
...
RIGHT(cast([ADJ_DATE] AS DATE), 5) DH
...
```

Which returns the column as the following format in a DataTable (`dt`):

```
11-15
11-13
11-20
11-14
```

Trying to do the following:

```
string dat = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("MM-dd"); // which returns 11-13
var k = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => dat == Convert.ToString(row.Field<DateTime>("DH"))); //should return the row with 11-13, but instead I get an error
```

Error:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

How can I update the code so I get the desired result back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `DateTime`

```
var k = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => dat == row.Field<string>("DH"));
```

The `RIGHT`

> Returns the right part of a character string with the specified number
>   of characters.

Please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx).

**Update**

If you want to get all the rows whose `DH` value is equal to `dat` then you should use the `Where` method:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => dat == row.Field<string>("DH"));
```

Comment: Field<string> will fail if DH is a DateTime column

Comment: I am getting no result back.

Comment: @Steve Since `RIGHT` returns a string how `DH` can be a `DateTime` column? I say so based on the sql that OP posted.

Comment: @Si8 Please do the following test, define a variable `dhs` like this  `var dhs = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row=>row.Field<string>).ToList();` Does `dhs` contains the correct values?

Comment: `k` just returns false or true, how can I get the returned row? I think it is working so far :)

Comment: If you want the row you have to filter the rows using the `Where` method.